# Spring - getting NullPointException when using @PostCostruct

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a `@PostCostruct` annotation to get an initializing method to run code at startup of my Sprin Boot application.

```
@Service("jobManager")
public class JobManager {

    @Autowired
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler;

    @Autowired
    InterruttoreService interruttoreService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createInitialJobs() throws SchedulerException {
        List<Interruttore> interruttori = interruttoreService.findAllSwitches();

        for (int i = 0; i < interruttori.size(); i++) {
            Interruttore interruttore = interruttori.get(i);
            interruttoreService.toggleSwitchOnStartup(interruttore); 

        }

    }
```

`interruttoreService.toggleSwitchOnStartup(interruttore)` 
is in a service class and is the following (job manager is auto wired in the this class)

```
@Override
    public void toggleSwitchOnStartup(Interruttore interruttore) {
        Date nextTimeout = interruttore.getTimeoutDate();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date now = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        if (nextTimeout == null) {
            nextTimeout = now;
        }
        int idInterruttore = interruttore.getIdInterruttore();

        if(nextTimeout.after(now)){ //c'è un timeout futuro

            try { lightOn(idInterruttore);
            jobManager.createJob(interruttore, nextTimeout);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {
            shutDown(idInterruttore);
        }

    }
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException when calling jobManager from this method, don't know why if the bean was created during @PostCostruct...

This is the stack trace of the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'interruttoreService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.besmart.service.InterruttoreServiceImpl.toggleSwitchOnStartup(InterruttoreServiceImpl.java:112)
    at it.besmart.service.InterruttoreServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$907e162e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at it.besmart.service.InterruttoreServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e2a6ab4b.toggleSwitchOnStartup(<generated>)
    at it.besmart.quartz.JobManager.createInitialJobs(JobManager.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 78 more
```

`interruttoreService` is auto wired correctly because just after the startup it starts working as usual.

Rergarding jobManager, i simply @Autowire it in InterruttoreService.class in this way

```
@Service("interruttoreService")
@Transactional
public class InterruttoreServiceImpl implements InterruttoreService {

    @Autowired
    JobManager jobManager;
....


....
```

Comment: Comment out the @PostConstruct and check if InterruttoreService is autowired correctly after startup. I suspect that the bean definition is wrong somehow which can cause the injection to not happen. Check if you have a bean for InterruttoreService. If you do, check that you have a bean for JobManager with the "jobManager" name.

Comment: can you post the exception? and the part of code where you are autowiring jobManager?

Comment: could you paste the code where you autowire the jobManager service?

Comment: thanks, I tried to answer to your comments

Comment: @besmart you forgot to add the code where you make the autowired of jobManager :)

Comment: @besmart did you checked what i said in my response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tightly coupled code (you have `InterruttoreService` injected into `JobManager` and at the same time `JobManager` injected into `InterruttoreService`).

Why don't you remove `InterruttoreService` injection from `JobManager` and let `toggleSwitchOnStartup()` complete within a `@PostCostruct` annotated method all in `InterruttoreService` directly where `JobManager` is already wired-up.

Comment: I am trying it, but now i'm getting an exception with Hibernate not able to obtain a Session to call `findAllSwitches`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a small typo with your service name

You have in your service

```
@Service("jobManager")//first j lowercase
public class JobManager {


@Autowired //In your Autowired if you dont say a qualifier name will try to find names as "JobManager" first J uppercase
JobManager jobManager;
```

Solution:

1. Remove the name in your service an keep only

   ```
   @Service
   public class JobManager {
   ```
2. Add a qualifier

   ```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("jobManager")
   JobManager jobManager;
   ```